# Best practice to define fields scope in C# script of Unity in regard to serialization?

Tags: unity, c#, monobehaviour

> I know from `Object Oriented Design` perspective that in order to provide `encapsulation`, we should avoid defining `public` variables in a `class` as much as we can and instead access them through public methods.

Currently, I working on a Unity project code base which defines most of the `fields` as `public` because It needs having to access them in Inspector tab of `Unity`. Was it better to defined fields as `private` and just added `[SerializableField]` attribute? Is there any drawback with doing so? I was wondering if there are any best practices for defining the scope of fields in the driven `Unity` classes?

**private fields:**

```
public class SampleClass: MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private Field sampleField;
}
```

**public fields:**

```
public class SampleClass: MonoBehaviour
{

    public Field sampleField;
}
```

Comment: This is largely a matter of your personal/studio coding style. If you're exposing a field to the inspector, you're already counting on external changes mucking with it and coding accordingly, so in practice from years of Unity development I haven't observed this use of `public` posing a significant source of bugs or debugging complications, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: In our code base we use private variables and public property's and use 3rd party Api too make serialized property's visible to the inspector.

Comment: @YoshSynergi May I know the name of that 3rd party API?

Comment: It's called Odin https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/89041